# default scope in older rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, find, default-scope

afternoon all.

i am working on a project written on rails 2.1

in newer versions we can use a rather cool method to create a default scope like so

```
  default_scope :order => 'title ASC'
```

how can the same/similar effect be achieved without upgrading the rails version?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider back-porting the default_scope functionality into your project.

I think [this is the commit](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2530d0eea8eaecd2c61f99225f050ff47973e9a0) that added default_scope.

You shoujld only need to make the changes shown in [active_record/base.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2530d0eea8eaecd2c61f99225f050ff47973e9a0#diff-1). The other parts are documentation and test, which you should consider adding but are not essential.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [utility_scopes](http://github.com/yfactorial/utility_scopes/tree) gem to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

[The has_finder gem](http://pivots.pivotallabs.com/users/nick/blog/articles/284-hasfinder-it-s-now-easier-than-ever-to-create-complex-re-usable-sql-queries) became named scopes in more recent versions of Rails. But I don't think it does default scopes.

[The global_scope plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dvisionfactory/) found here seems to do what you want.